# Protocol buffer worse performance than JSON

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am profiling my protocol buffer de-serialization performance and found it's a magnitude (proto: `0.2GB/s` yyjson: `1GB/s`) worse than [JSON](https://github.com/ibireme/yyjson_benchmark) with [this data set](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark/blob/master/data/canada.json). And thought it is not reasonable at all, since most of the data is floating point numbers.

```
syntax = "proto2";
option optimize_for = SPEED;
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Canada 
{
    message Properties 
    {
        required string name = 1;
    }

    message Geometry 
    {
        required string type = 1;
        repeated google.protobuf.ListValue coordinates = 2;
    }

    message Features 
    {
        required string type = 1;
        required Properties properties = 2;
        required Geometry geometry = 3;
    }

    required string type = 1;
    repeated Features features = 2;
}
```

The benchmark related code

```cpp
template<typename MessageType>
void Parse(MessageType& m, google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream& data)
{
    m.ParseFromZeroCopyStream(&data);
}

int main()
{
    std::string data = ReadFileAsBinary("...");
    google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream s{ data.data(), (int)data.size() };
    Canada parsedFromFile;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    {
        Parse(parsedFromFile, s);
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //... more code
}
```

My intuition tells me that parsing the `ListValue` type could be the main cause, but I don't know how to optimize it better, since it's a "array-of-array" in the original json data.

EDIT:
Both of the numbers above are measured on my own pc. Both compiled with MSVC, with `/O2 /Oi /Ot /arch:AVX2`

Comment: I am not sure, why you would expect the same performance from protobuf vs json, while protobuf does a load more type checking and stuff.

Comment: I think it's "reasonable" assumption, since in this case the majority of the data are numbers. If the deserialization performance is 5 times as bad, what would be the benefit of using it other than saving about 50% of spaces?

Comment: But the parsing + verifying against the data model is significantly more complex with protobuf protocols than with json, which doesn't have a fixed data type scheme at all during the data is parsed. Validating json, is comparably simple.

Comment: What does the performance of the program overall look like? i.e. when you actually do something with the data.